# kolmogorov-complexity is not as a mathematics problem, score has to be inferior

Tags: discussion

## [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) problems are not like mathematics problems

The way of see generate from the set of problems tag as kolmogorov-complexity is anti programming... one algorithm in mathematics (here with tag [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) or [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)) is something ok and useful; but kolmogorov-complexity problem goes against the right way of seeing programming; and so can not have the same score for vote of a question or answer with [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) or [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) questions. Should upvotes for an answer on a [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) question yield not 10 reputation, but say 5 or 1?

Comment: I know there is some language barrier involved and I tried my best to infer what you try to state, however I'm not sure what you mean by *"score has to be inferior"* or *"can not have the same score for vote"*. Could you try to rephrase what you want to change about the scoring?

Comment: @Laikoni when someone vote for an answer on question with tag kolmogorov-complexity the score not has to increase by 10 but by 5 or 1

Comment: Ok, so in your opinion answers to [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] are upvoted to much in comparison to answers to harder [tag:math] challenges?

Comment: If that's the case then this question is more or less a dupe of [Non-Trivial Answers get too few upvotes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13128/56433).

Comment: @Laikoni yes; but more: when mat or number tags make to go in a good way, Kolmogorov-complexity make to go in a wrong way again readability and easy algorithms representation... too much synthesis can be wrong (at last for me)

Comment: This is not a math-only site, you know. Sure, sometimes [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] answers can be boring, but that's not the tags fault. 30% of my rep and my answers are from [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] answers, and I very much would like to keep that fact; I personally don't find mathy questions that fun, but that doesn't mean I'll try to remove the fun from others.

Comment: [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] and [tag:math] are not exclusive. In fact, IMO the most interesting KC question is [in the intersection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9070/194), and that intersection is the best bet for future KC questions which don't come down to the same old grammar compression tricks.

Comment: Also, a technical problem: we don't implement the voting system, SE does. And our feature requests are often ignored.

Answer (score 10):

Assigning different amounts of reputation to upvotes on challenges bearing a certain tag is a bad idea. Being a math problem doesn't automatically make a challenge more difficult or useful.

There are [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges that are hard to golf (even if writing an ungolfed solution is straightforward), while there are [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) challenges that simply ask to [add two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84260/12012).